# what does java8 stream map do here?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I was confused about the difference between `map()` and `forEach()` method in java8 stream. For instance,

```
List<String> strings = Lists.newArrayList("1", "2");
Map<String, String> map = Maps.newHashMap();
strings.stream().map(s->map.put(s, s));
System.out.println(map);
```

I got empty output here, but if I change map to `forEach()` just like

```
List<String> strings = Lists.newArrayList("1", "2");
Map<String, String> map = Maps.newHashMap();
strings.stream().forEach(s->map.put(s, s));
System.out.println(map);
```

I can get

> {1=1, 2=2}

Why it just didn't run `map()` method? What's difference between them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
strings.stream().map(s->map.put(s, s));
```

does nothing, since the stream pipeline is not processed until you execute a terminal operation. Therefore the `Map` remains empty.

Adding a terminal operation to the stream pipeline will cause `map.put(s, s)` to be executed for each element of the `Stream` required by the terminal operation (some terminal operations require just one element, while others require all elements of the `Stream`).

On the other hand, the second stream pipeline:

```
strings.stream().forEach(s->map.put(s, s));
```

ends with a terminal operation - `forEach` - which is executed for each element of the `Stream`.

That said, both snippets are misusing `Stream`s. In order to populate a `Collection` or a `Map` based on the contents of the `Stream`, you should use `collect()`, which can create a `Map` or a `Collection` and populate it however you like. `forEach` and `map` have different purposes.

For example, to create a `Map`:

```
List<String> strings = Lists.newArrayList("1", "2");
Map<String, String> map = strings.stream()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                                                           Function.identity()));
System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 9):

The difference is this:

- The idea of `forEach()` is to "work" on each element of the underlying collection (by having a **side effect**) whereas
- `map()` is about applying a method on each object and putting the **result** of that into a new stream

That is also the reason why your `stream().map()` doesn't result in something - because you **throw** away the new stream created by the `map()` call!

In that sense, the *signatures* of the two methods tell you that:

```
void forEach(BiConsumer<? super K,? super V> action)
```

> Performs the given action for each entry in this map until all entries have been processed

versus

```
 <R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.

And for the record: only `map()` is a **stream** method - `forEach()` exists for both, streams and Collections/Iterables.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for each instance method of `Stream` states whether the method is an *intermediate* operation, or a *terminal* operation. Only terminal operations will cause the stream to be evaluated. Intermediate operations may not be performed unless required by a downstream terminal operation.

This can improve efficiency, especially when the terminal operation is a *short-circuit* operation, like `findAny()`. A pipeline with a complex set of intermediate operations doesn't need to be executed for additional elements after a matching element has been found.

In your case, `forEach()` is a terminal operation; it causes the pipeline to be executed. `map()` is an intermediate operation; it doesn't have to do anything unless required by a downstream terminal operation.

Answer (score -1):

You should use

`stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s,s -> s)`

...or something along those lines, instead of `stream().map(...)`